# Javascript on click go to other div

Tags: jquery

currently, i have a comment box, where user can comment, however when too many comment on it, the page stretches down. so when user press comment, the box appear, however user have to scroll down to comment.

how do i achieve when user click comment box, page slide down to comment box or straight go to comment box?

i;m using jquery..

Comment: do you have a working sample for us to see html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you give the comment box the id="comment-box" attribute and just use a link h
href="#comment-box" on a link that say 'go to comment box'?

Comment: doing this will add index.php#comment-box right? which screw up other thing on my web.

Comment: What does it screw up? It's just a link?

What I mean is adding <a rel="comment section" href="#comment-box" title="Go to comment box">Go to comment box</a> from that place.

Comment: Oh, I guess it works now as my answer got accepted.

I luuuvvv giving extremely simple solutions to complicated problems.